# Stack Exchange API: create a question with an embedded Image

Tags: support, images, api

I have been looking at the API for some time and can discern no ready answer: Is it possible to create a question using the API, which contains embedded images?

I can achieve the same by replicating the actions of the front end in code, however I can see no clear way of doing this in the API.

I value any information with evidence which you may be able to provide.

Comment: [This is not possible](https://stackapps.com/questions/2664/is-there-an-api-to-upload-images-to-ses-imgur-installation). You'll have to upload the image manually and just insert the proper markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) for confirming this: it appears that there is [no  facility](https://stackapps.com/questions/2664/is-there-an-api-to-upload-images-to-ses-imgur-installation) for achieving the exact functionality of the front end, but that there is a corollary method which can be used.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

[There *used to be* a way](https://stackapps.com/a/8657/34061) if you use an access token and request key from one of the Stack Exchange mobile app to upload the image. It [does not work anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/295232) now that the mobile apps have been discontinued; one of my scripts now simply tries to mimic browser requests (logging in, and using the image uploader).

> You'll need to make a POST call to https://mobile.stackexchange.com/1/image/upload and supply the following parameters (as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`):
>
> - `access_token`
> - `key` (the iOS app uses `kJ1geZUa*oJVMN229qwESg((`, the Android app `r0aEx)wmOcRhhPMdffXeUQ((`)
> - `image_mime_type`: `image/png`, `image/jpeg` or `image/gif` (other image types are not supported)
> - `image_name`: just a random string, doesn't really matter
> - `filter`: `vqc7J` (I have no idea which fields these correspond to, since this call is not documented)
> - `image_data`: the image data, encoded as Base64
>
> If the upload succeeds, you'll get the URL back (the response is in the usual API style, a root object with an `items` array; there'll be a single item with a `url` property).

You can then use this URL in the Markdown you supply to the [create question API method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question). Of course, it might be easier using another image hosting server, but keeping it on Stack Exchange's imgur channel is commendable.