# On which day did it become impossible to upload images via the SE mobile app?

Tags: support, images, uploader, mobile-app, stack-exchange-history

Still trying to understand why [some images and GIF files hosted on i.stack.imgur.com larger than 2 MiB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395755/178179), I wonder the following: on which day did it become impossible to upload images via the SE mobile app? I couldn't find a clear answer looking at [Updated: Mobile app infrastructure has been decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/178179).

Comment: Probably only in December 12th (2022) when Spencer added "Mobile has been shut down in its entirety" to the announcement you linked.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Maybe. Features stopped working progressively.

Comment: Its very hard to tell cause the breakage  was gradual - I had it crashing on android 12, but not an older version. In theory it would have worked right till the mobile app infra was decomissioned, but the phone I had older android on was.. odd

Comment: Sure, but knowing how it works, people could still technically use the app API and upload images with it, one of the mods here (Glorfindel) was doing that for example.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Thanks. Did the app API stop working on December 12th (2022)?

Comment: Can't say for 100% but yeah, 99% that the API stopped working on that day. Pinged Glorfindel in chat already about the large images post, if he'll reply there I'll ask him about that detail as well.

Answer (score 12):

I'm pretty sure that happened in [the week of December 12th, 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/295232).

> Mobile has been shut down in its entirety as of December 12th, 2022.

I have a commit in the repository of my broken image repairer script dated December 19th, which replaces the [(mobile-app-exclusive) API call](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350381/295232) with something to simulate the upload via the website instead. I'm pretty sure I would only have done so because the API call did not work anymore. Deleted comments under the linked answer indicate it was still working on November 29th, 2022.